# Seed Stack i18n AddOn Issue for language translation

Tags: internationalization, seedstack

Hell Team,

While using LocalizationService.localize(key, value) for key translation it gives the below exception,

1. javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
      at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
2. org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
      at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
3. java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'translatio1_.Key_ID' in 'field list'
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in DDL scripts provided as part of the addon source code: scripts for mysql and Oracle are outdated. Correct structure is available in the script for hsql: TRANS_ID_FK column in table SEED_I18N_KEY_TRANS should now be named KEY_ID.

A [ticket](https://github.com/seedstack/i18n-addon/issues/37) has been opened on Github for correction follow-up.